# Resetting InDesign's "Document modified outside of book" warning

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs5, book

This feels more like a Super User question than Graphic Design, but I figure someone here will be more likely to know the answer.

Using InDesign 5, I have a "book" collection that I use to keep a bunch of files in one place. Apparently at some point I opened up and modified two of the files apart from the book file, yielding this little warning:

[image: Book palette with warning highlighted]

My question is, how do I get rid of the warning, short of removing the file from the book and reinserting it? I figured there has to be a better way. I would have assumed that opening the file from the book, editing, and saving would have reset it, but that hasn't been the case.

Answer (score 3):

"Update all cross-references" from the fly-out menu should do the trick. (sorts it out for me in CS6). It's the equivalent of 'Update all links' in the Links window, for placed files within a document.

Or if that's greyed out, "Synchronise book" might help?

Comment: Neither worked (Well, I tried "synchronize selected documents" instead of "synchronize book", which I couldn't find). I tried "Update all Numbers" which worked, but also screwed up all of my page numbers! When I changed them back I got more warnings. Perhaps I'm just using this feature in a way it wasn't intended to be used...

Comment: Did you check the synchronise options? Master Pages is unticked by default for me, might be related. Also, I find the Adobe forums best for questions like this - sometimes it's a bug or corruption or something (sounds possible in this case) and those guys seem to know every bug inside out.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem using CC, and I knew that no document had been modified outside the indb file.
My book has individual indd files for each chapter, and my solution for this error was to update the contents page in the first file (layout/update table of contents)
As each chapter was updated the error sign disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and resolved it by removing the document from the book, then re-adding.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of those annoying info warnings from your book, open the book in InDesign. Select all of the documents in the book.
From the flyout menu, click "preflight book." If you have no errors, all of those warnings will disappear.

Comment: Using InDesign CC v9.2.1 this did not work. The book with the warning passed the preflight tests (got the green dot), the warning disappeared for a second and came back. The green dot disappeared as well and was replaced with the question mark... so back to square one.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was to remove the document and add it back in.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution may depend on what triggered the warning. In my case, I believe it was triggered when I added new documents & pages which threw off page numbering across all the documents in the book.

My solution was to open the book, select all the documents in the book, then select **Update Numbering > Update All Numbers** from the book panel's drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

In the Book Panel drop down menu there is 'Book page numbering options...'. Then choose 'Update page and section numbers'. This will fix all docs in the book. You may need to go back inside to see if pagination is affected in each doc.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot to your answer to make it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, I selected all files in the INDB panel by clicking the last file then, while holding the Shift key, selected the top file. I then clicked the menu icon in the upper right corner of the panel (three horizontal bars), selected "Update Numbering," then selected "Update Page and Selection Numbers." It worked! Yay!

Answer (score -1):

Got the same yellow error...Go to book properties in the drop down list select Update Numbering option then select update all numbers